# The problem didnt show up on my Problem tab, but there is panic when i am trying to run it

Tags: go, build, compiler-errors

I make 3 go files with each of them is using the same package, which was package main.
It will look like this...

```
mydir/
-client.go 
-room.go
-main.go
```

In my terminal, there is no problem that appears on it, but when I try to run/build main.go, it's returning a panic:

```
undefined: newRoom
```

here was my snippet code which has panic :

```
//main.go
r := newRoom()

//room.go
func newRoom() *room{
   return &room{}
}
```

When I try to delete the function, it's returning an error "Undeclared" in Visual Code. When adding it again, the problem disappears but when I try to run or build it, it returns an error if my newRoom function is undefined. Does anybody have a clue, what's wrong with it?

It's better if answered with some explanation why it doesn't appear on Visual Code Problems output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the command to build a binary from a directory with a bunch of files:

```
go build ./mydir/...
```

This command build the package in the `mydir` folder and all packages recursing down. Run `go help build` to get more about `build` command.

There is no any issue with your code.

Answer (score 5):

When you try to build `main.go` the compiler can see only the `main.go` file that why error was shown like "undefined new room"
you should use `go build .` instead of `go build main.go` if you have multiple go file in first level of your directory.